# tab data to be displayed in individual tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm working on angular bootstrap tabs. I want to show different content in each tab when user navigates through the tabs. 
I could not able to show the content in individual tabs. Please find the demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/PoAKHeZuBly5TWYWMOxF?p=info)

js code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('tabs', [ 'ui.bootstrap']);
myApp.controller('tabsctrl', function ($rootScope,$scope) {
          $rootScope.tabName ='MyTab Name';

    $rootScope.tabValue="tab1Value";
    $scope.applicationData = {};
    $scope.activeModule = "tab1Value";
    $scope.programModules=[{"tabName":"Tab1","tabValue":"tab1Value"},{"tabName":"Tab2","tabValue":"tab2Value"}];
    $scope.loadApplicationData = function(tabVal,tabName){
        $rootScope.tabName =tabName;
     alert("$rootScope.tabName :: "+$rootScope.tabName);
        $rootScope.tabValue=tabVal;
        $scope.activeModule = tabVal;

    }; 
    $scope.loadApplicationData($scope.activeModule,'Tab1');


});
```

html code:

```
<div ng-controller="tabsctrl">
 <div class="top-tabs">
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" >
            <li role="presentation" class="{{ pg.tabValue == activeModule? 'active':''}}" ng-repeat="pg in programModules">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)"  ng-click="loadApplicationData(pg.tabValue,pg.tabName)" >{{pg.tabName}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

         <div class="tab-content">
          <!--Tab1 data div-->
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                 Tab1 data
                            </div>This should be shown when user click tab1
                            </div>
                            </div><div></div>
              <!--Tab2 data div-->
              <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab2">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                 Tab2 data
                            </div>This should be shown when user click tab2
                            </div>
                            </div><div></div>  </div>
                            </div></div>
```

When user click on tab1, tab1 div should be shown, similarly when user click on Tab2, tab2 data should be displayed and Tab2 should be selected.Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: @charlietfl - Currently this is my example link http://plnkr.co/edit/PoAKHeZuBly5TWYWMOxF?p=info . Can i use the same js code to achieve the functionality as in my application i already have this code.thanks

Comment: Read the angular-ui-bootstrap tabs docs. You aren't using their directive but you are including the module in page

Comment: As charlietfl has mentioned, use Angular UI Bootstrap. Here is the info you are looking for [angular-ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/0.14.3/#/tabs)
Here is an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/BsfDWSFILiJeJ04Nzlvy?p=preview)

Comment: @pedro - ThankYou, i understand but being a newbie facing difficulties. As i mentioned in my post, i will be having multiple <div>'s to be displayed in the tab and each tab has unique data to be displayed. With the example you mentioned i cannot use <div> directly in my page. Please advice.

Comment: @pedro - Thanks for the example link. I think that should work but how to show the corresponding <div> in the tabs. Please see the http://plnkr.co/edit/fv8oevUUOeVEDXmv1LcF?p=preview. When user click on tab1 ,tab1 div should be shown and when user click on tab2 , tab2 div should be shown, Please suggest what changes need to be done.

Answer (score 1):

This how u can achieve it i have updated your html as there were lots of end div tag missing and i have just add conditions as per your code style

```
<div ng-app="tabs">

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.js"></script>
<script src="example.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div ng-controller="tabsctrl">
    <div class="top-tabs">
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation" class="{{ pg.tabValue == activeModule? 'active':''}}" ng-repeat="pg in programModules">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="loadApplicationData(pg.tabValue,pg.tabName)">{{pg.tabName}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div ng-if="tabName === 'Tab1'" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                Tab1 data
                            </div>This should be shown when user click tab1
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div ng-if="tabName === 'Tab2'" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab2">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                Tab2 data
                            </div>This should be shown when user click tab2
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But using ng-if in html and checking with tabName is not the correct way in realtime application i guess. In future if tabName need to be changed i have to modify js as well as html code which is not preferable. Please advice.Can we do in better approach.Thanks

Comment: this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/BsfDWSFILiJeJ04Nzlvy?p=preview is the correct way to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to do what you are asking would be to use `ng-include`. See [plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/BsfDWSFILiJeJ04Nzlvy?p=preview)

```
var myApp = angular.module('tabs', [ 'ui.bootstrap']);
myApp.controller('tabsctrl', function ($rootScope,$scope) {

    $scope.tabs = [
      {"tabName":"Tab1","tabValue":"tab1Value","templateURL":"tab1.html"},
      {"tabName":"Tab2","tabValue":"tab2Value","templateURL":"tab2.html"}
    ];

});

<div ng-app="tabs">

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <div ng-controller="tabsctrl">
    <uib-tabset>
      <uib-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.tabName}}" active="tab.active" disable="tab.disabled">
        <div ng-include="tab.templateURL"></div>
      </uib-tab>
    </uib-tabset>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to display some tab buttons to switch out content based on the selected tab. I'm not sure if you are trying to only show the content of the selected tab or some content of all tabs and extra content of the selected one, so I've provided an example of both.

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/qpzDqrPz8rvUDVsOGA3o?p=preview)

```
function controller($scope){
    $scope.tabs = [
        {name: 'Tab 1', value1: 'Tab 1 value 1', value2: 'Tab 1 value 2'},
        {name: 'Tab 2', value1: 'Tab 2 value 1', value2: 'Tab 2 value 2'},
    ];
    $scope.selectedTab = $scope.tabs[0];

    $scope.selectTab = function(tab){
        $scope.selectedTab = tab;
    };
}
```

Html example 1

```
<div ng-repeat="tab in tabs"
     ng-click="selectTab(tab)"
     ng-class="{'selected': tab == selectedTab}">
    {{tab.name}}
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
    {{selectedTab.value1}}
</div>
```

Html example 2

```
<div ng-repeat="tab in tabs"
     ng-click="selectTab(tab)"
     ng-class="{'selected': tab == selectedTab}">
    {{tab.name}}
</div>
<div ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
  {{tab.value1}}
  <div ng-if="tab === selectedTab">
    {{tab.value2}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Obviously you can style and build this up however you like.
You shouldn't need anything special to achieve what you want.

I recommend you don't use $rootScope, I'm not sure what you are achieving with it here.
I also recommend you use directives or components where possible instead of attaching 'ng-controller' to arbitrary bits of html.